# Flex Wrap: Wrap making margins below a row of div's

Tags: html, css, flexbox

http://tsuts.tskoli.is/2t/2809984199/skapalon/ <-- Hosted Here.

The Classes Container and Projectskort are the ones that are to look at.

```
.container{
display: flex;
min-height: 100vh;
width: calc(100vw - 500px);
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: space-between;
margin: 0 auto;
}  
.projectskort{
margin-top: 10px;
width: 224px;
height: 270px;
border-radius: 3px;
background-color: white;
}
```

Any help is much obliged, Thanks.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the `align-content` default of `stretch` which is spreading the lines over the full height of the section. You need to set that to `flex-start`

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: calc(100vw - 500px);
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 0 auto;
    align-content: flex-start;
}
```

Comment: Works now. Haven't quite got the hang of flex just yet, Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The margins you are referring to are being created because your flex has a hard written height on it.

You are forcing the flex to fill 100vh, and with 2 lines of content, each is filling 50% of that.

if you add more divs for a third line, you will see they all take up 33% of the containers height.

To try and replicate what you want, remove the min height from your flex container, put your flex container in a wrapping container with min-height 100vh.